# how to set image size limit in c# (eg; <150kb )

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a project in c# , I want to upload images in to database if its size is <150 kb . How to set the limitation for uploading images? I don't know how to expand it ?  please help thanks in advance

```
private void Browsebutton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "images only.|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png";
        DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
        //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;

        textBox5.Text = ofd.FileName;
}
```

Comment: You can use the [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get the file size - if it's greater than 150 KB, don't upload it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get the file size. The number of bytes are accessible by `FileInfo.Length`

```
if (new FileInfo(ofd.FileName).Length > (150 * 1024))
{
    throw new ApplicationException(); //handle invalid file size here
}
```